# Shortcut for Replace button in "Find and Replace" dialog

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys, shortcut

I call up Find and Replace dialog with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. On <kbd>F3</kbd> it finds the result but then I must hunt the Replace button using the mouse. And on every new find, it changes the screen position. Is there any way to use this dialog using only keyboard?

It will save me a few  precious seconds multiplied by some very large number (I'm in the middle of heavy refactoring).

Comment: Try to use refactoring feature if available, like rename

Comment: [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) or something similar might be the way to go if you do a lot of refactoring. Alternatively, you could learn [Visual Studio Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx). They are not that dissimilar from PCRE. Also, if you need help learning regex, [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) is a useful tool for testing REs (only the PCRE style ones I think, but again the syntax isn't that different).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry,

As microsoft there is no keyboard shortcut as Replace Next,

You can check this url

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

Answer (score 22):

In visual studio 2015:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> opens the Replace dialog.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> opens the Find dialog.

Within that dialog:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> - Focus "Fi**n**d" entry field
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - Focus "Re**p**lace with" entry field
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Toggle Match **C**ase
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - Toggle Whole **W**ord
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - Toggle Regular **E**xpressions
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - Open "**L**ook In" dropdown list. Use Up/Down and Enter to select from this list:

  - Current Block
  - Selection
  - Current Document
  - All Open Documents
  - Current Project
  - Current Solution
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - **R**eplace Next
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Replace **A**ll
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> - Dismiss dialog

For example, to replace "foo" with "bar" within the current selection:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - Opens the Replace dialog, with focus on "Search Term".

  - Enter "foo"
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - Focus is now on "Replacement Term"

  - Enter "bar"
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, choose "Selection", press Enter.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - Whole word only
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - Replace first term
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> - Close replace dialog.

Comment: This is the answer.  Now I just need to figure out how ReSharper screwed up my Alt-R (Replace Next).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply copy your desired replacement text before starting to <kbd>F3</kbd> through your source text, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> when you hit the next match as VS selects the match text for you.

It is a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you dock the find/replace window then it will not move with each new find.

You can then alternate with 1 finger on F3 to move to next find, while hovering the mouse over the non-moving replace button to replace what you need.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to deactivate Resharper default behavior of "Alt+R" which provides a quick access to Resharper menu in Visual Studio.

Just uncheck it in Resharpers options:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDHe6.png)

Comment: This is the real reason in my case why the shortcut doesn't work anymore.